# Как добавить класс всем элементам с классом равным ID выбранного элемента?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Имеется 2 списка.

Первый:

```
 <ul>
   <li class="lek" id="867" class="lek">
      <span class="867">text1</span>
   </li>

   <li class="lek" id="865" class="lek">
      <span class="865">text2</span>
   </li>

   <li class="lek" id="863" class="lek">
      <span class="863">text3</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Второй:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="859 866 870" href="detail.php?id=933">aaa</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="863" href="detail.php?id=932">bbb</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="859 860 863 865 870" href="detail.php?id=931">ccc</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо, чтобы при клике, например, на "text3", всем элементам с классом "863" добавлялся класс "select".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.lek > span').click(function(){
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    // var className = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + parentId).addClass('select');
});
```

- [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)
- [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Класс добавляется текущему элементу, а нужно чтобы всем элементам на странице.

Comment: т.е. даже несуществующим в данный момент на странице? тов. @karmadro4 когда-то предлагал способ динамического добавления стилей в css, [вот](http://hashcode.ru/questions/113177/#answer-container-113224) попробуйте

Comment: Нет, только существующим. В вашем варианте класс "select" добавляется к элементу по которому кликнул, т.е. к элементу "span".

Comment: >В вашем варианте класс "select" добавляется к элементу по которому кликнул

[нет](http://jsfiddle.net/QPHpC/)

если нужно, чтобы добавлялся только к ссылкам, например, измените селектор на `$('a.' + parentId)`

Comment: Странно, у меня почему то не работает

Comment: Ага, нашел причину почему у меня не работало, к элементам нижнего списка к классам почему то добавлялся пробел "&nbsp;" и поэтому код не срабатывал.

Comment: Зачем создавать отдельную переменную `parentId`? Это имело бы место, если бы `$(this).parent().attr('id')` использовалось бы где-либо еще, но здесь обращение только в одном месте используется.

Answer (score 3):

1. [.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)
2. [.addClass()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)